# Threads using same method in parallel

Tags: java, multithreading

Is it possible to have this behavior:

One thread (T1) calls some method, for instance, `compute(10);`

While that function is still executing, another thread calls it again (with other parameters), say, `compute(20);`

If the method

```
public int compute(int i) {
    return i+20;
}
```

will each thread get the correct result?

I expect that T1 gets `20`, and T2 gets `40`.

Comment: Well, T1 would get 30, yes. I suggest you write some code and try it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you use *local variables only* (method parameters are local), **yes it is safe.**

```
public class Computer {
    public int compute(int i) {
        return i+20;
    }
}
```

If you would use *instance variables* or *static variables*, then you should have `synchronized` every `read` and `write` to the variables.

```
public class Computer {
    private int increment;

    public synchronized int compute(int i) {
        return i+increment;  // <-- reads increment
    }

    private synchronized void setIncrement(int increment) {
         this.increment = increment;  // <-- writes increment
    }
}
```

Comment: Accepted this answer as the correct one because it's the more complete.

Answer (score 1):

Short answer, yes. Each thread gets its own stack of data that is used in the method, which is totally separate from other threads. You only have to worry about conflicts when data (for example class level variables) is ***shared*** between the threads.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your `compute` method implementation is:

```
int compute(int i) {
  return i + 20;
}
```

Then the each thread will get correct result as this method not using shared state.